# show/hide divs to filter with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to be able to apply and show the results from more than 1 filter at a time e.g so I can select 'High' and 'pizza' and display the results from both of these, currently I can only get it to switch between filters and display the results from the 1 selected.

https://jsfiddle.net/f7srx0dd/

```
<div class="nav">
<a href="#" data-category-type="high">high</a>

<a href="#" data-category-type="low" data-category-name="air">low</a>

<a href="#" data-category-name="pizza">pizza</a>

</div>
<div id="Categories">
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="high" data-category-  name="pizza">high</div>
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="low" data-category-name="pasta">low</div>
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="low" data-category-name="pizza">low</div>
    <div class="hide" data-category-type="high" data-category-name="pasta">high</div>
</div>

$('.nav a').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var cat = $(this).data('categoryType');
var nam = $(this).data('categoryName');
$('#Categories > div').hide();
$('#Categories > div[data-category-type="'+cat+'"]').show();
$('#Categories > div[data-category-name="'+nam+'"]').show();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You can not use $(this) for getting both category and name.

With the click function, $(this) will always give you the clicked element. And as in your case, same element, is not necessarily having information of both the category and name.

Hence, you need to update either your html, so that all the anchors have both the data attributes or need to update your function so as category and name is picked from the valid source.

I will be creating a sample for you to explain it further.

This is the one with html update, in which anchors have both the data attributes

like

```
<a href="#" data-category-type="high"  data-category-name="pizza">High and pizza</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f7srx0dd/4/

This one is with the javascript update

https://jsfiddle.net/f7srx0dd/5/

Hope you find the results useful!!

Comment: That's exactly what I was after but I need to be able to use a checkbox, updated https://jsfiddle.net/f7srx0dd/7/ , it's not showing whether the checkbox is ticked or not, is there something that needs to be added in the

Comment: Please remove -  e.preventDefault(); from the click handler.

Comment: just noticed that on load it displays all results and then after it's ticked and unticked it won't display anything, how can I get it to display all results after it is unticked?

Comment: Let me check this for you

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/f7srx0dd/10/ - In case no one is selected you were not showing any selection. Updated code for fallback.

Answer (score 1):

In order to handle multiple filters, you can toggle a class each time you click a link.  (Note that this functionality lends itself better to *buttons*, not anchors.  But I'll use anchors to match your HTML.)

```
$('.nav a').on('click', function (e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  $('#Categories > div').hide();

  $('.selected').each(function() {
    var cat= $(this).data('categoryType');
    var nam= $(this).data('categoryName');
    $('#Categories > div[data-category-type="'+cat+'"]').show();
    $('#Categories > div[data-category-name="'+nam+'"]').show();
  });
});
```

This code toggles a class called `selected`, and it iterates through each of the selected item's `categoryType` and `categoryName` to determine what to include in the filter.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2rdzwuf9/2)

Comment: Again, exactly what i'm after but using a checkbox instead of nav doesn't work? - http://jsfiddle.net/2rdzwuf9/3/

Comment: just noticed that on load it displays all results and then after it's ticked and unticked it won't display anything, how can I get it to display all results after it is unticked?

Comment: Change the `click` handler to a `change` handler, and call `change()` when you load the page:  http://jsfiddle.net/kfz8kt94/

Answer (score 1):

You would need to set a selected on and off state on the buttons to know which ones you have selected and then turn them off by clicking them again (if I understand your question correctly). So in your click event you would set up something like this:

```
if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
    $this.removeClass('selected');
} else {
    $this.addClass('selected');
}
```

And then loop through the links to show the ones selected.

I updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f7srx0dd/2/

Comment: That's great exactly what I'm after, I'd like to use checkboxes instead - http://jsfiddle.net/2rdzwuf9/3/ however when I change .nav to checkbox it doesn't work?

Comment: here https://jsfiddle.net/2rdzwuf9/4/ you were still using the .nav a selector when you switched your selector to not longer be .nav a but rather just input[type="checkbox"]. I wrapped it in a .nav div and changed the selector.